# Intercepting monitorEnter - Resulting byte code cannot be JIT compiled

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

In my agent I am intercepting `monitorEnter` events. The interceptor function so far does nothing but return immediately. Since I was facing some big performance impacts I was trying to figure out what's wrong.

My current understanding is that the modified bytecode works but JIT has problems compiling it. I am not sure why yet and what would be the best way to fix that.

The naive approach to intercept all `monitorEnter` was to `DUP` the monitor, perform `monitorenter` followed by an `INVOKESTATIC` to my interceptor passing the monitor object. Doing so sometimes led to an `IllegalMonitorStateException` though. (not sure why yet). I then changed the code sequence to `monitorEnter`, `ALOAD` , `INVOKESTATIC` to my interceptor. While I have not experienced the exception again, the resulting code cannot be JIT compiled (actually also the DUP version cannot).

Here the sample byte code of a method that is causing the problem (class `com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl`). The only code added by me are instructions at 12 and 13:

```
  protected final void checkColumnBounds(int) throws java.sql.SQLException;
    descriptor: (I)V
    flags: ACC_PROTECTED, ACC_FINAL
    Code:
      stack=5, locals=4, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: invokevirtual #319                // Method checkClosed:()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection;
         4: invokeinterface #323,  1          // InterfaceMethod com/mysql/jdbc/MySQLConnection.getConnectionMutex:()Ljava/lang/Object;
         9: dup
        10: astore_2
        11: monitorenter
        12: aload_2
        13: invokestatic  #329                // Method com/test/bootstrap/Interceptor.monitorEntered:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        16: iload_1
        17: iconst_1
        18: if_icmpge     60
        21: ldc_w         #516                // String ResultSet.Column_Index_out_of_range_low
        24: iconst_2
        25: anewarray     #121                // class java/lang/Object
        28: dup
        29: iconst_0
        30: iload_1
        31: invokestatic  #470                // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        34: aastore
        35: dup
        36: iconst_1
        37: aload_0
        38: getfield      #236                // Field fields:[Lcom/mysql/jdbc/Field;
        41: arraylength
        42: invokestatic  #470                // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        45: aastore
        46: invokestatic  #519                // Method com/mysql/jdbc/Messages.getString:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
        49: ldc_w         #521                // String S1009
        52: aload_0
        53: invokevirtual #506                // Method getExceptionInterceptor:()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ExceptionInterceptor;
        56: invokestatic  #512                // Method com/mysql/jdbc/SQLError.createSQLException:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ExceptionInterceptor;)Ljava/sql/SQLException;
        59: athrow
        60: iload_1
        61: aload_0
        62: getfield      #236                // Field fields:[Lcom/mysql/jdbc/Field;
        65: arraylength
        66: if_icmple     108
        69: ldc_w         #523                // String ResultSet.Column_Index_out_of_range_high
        72: iconst_2
        73: anewarray     #121                // class java/lang/Object
        76: dup
        77: iconst_0
        78: iload_1
        79: invokestatic  #470                // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        82: aastore
        83: dup
        84: iconst_1
        85: aload_0
        86: getfield      #236                // Field fields:[Lcom/mysql/jdbc/Field;
        89: arraylength
        90: invokestatic  #470                // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
        93: aastore
        94: invokestatic  #519                // Method com/mysql/jdbc/Messages.getString:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
        97: ldc_w         #521                // String S1009
       100: aload_0
       101: invokevirtual #506                // Method getExceptionInterceptor:()Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ExceptionInterceptor;
       104: invokestatic  #512                // Method com/mysql/jdbc/SQLError.createSQLException:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ExceptionInterceptor;)Ljava/sql/SQLException;
       107: athrow
       108: aload_0
       109: getfield      #196                // Field profileSql:Z
       112: ifne          122
       115: aload_0
       116: getfield      #214                // Field useUsageAdvisor:Z
       119: ifeq          131
       122: aload_0
       123: getfield      #164                // Field columnUsed:[Z
       126: iload_1
       127: iconst_1
       128: isub
       129: iconst_1
       130: bastore
       131: aload_2
       132: monitorexit
       133: goto          141
       136: astore_3
       137: aload_2
       138: monitorexit
       139: aload_3
       140: athrow
       141: return
      Exception table:
         from    to  target type
            16   133   136   any
           136   139   136   any
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0     142     0  this   Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ResultSetImpl;
            0     142     1 columnIndex   I
      LineNumberTable:
        line 760: 0
        line 761: 16
        line 762: 21
        line 766: 60
        line 767: 69
        line 773: 108
        line 774: 122
        line 776: 131
        line 777: 141
      StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 6
        frame_type = 252 /* append */
          offset_delta = 60
          locals = [ class java/lang/Object ]
        frame_type = 47 /* same */
        frame_type = 13 /* same */
        frame_type = 8 /* same */
        frame_type = 68 /* same_locals_1_stack_item */
          stack = [ class java/lang/Throwable ]
        frame_type = 4 /* same */
    Exceptions:
      throws java.sql.SQLException
```

The asm code used in the method visitor is this:

```
        if (opcode == MONITORENTER)
        {
//          super.visitInsn(DUP); // in the beginning I used DUP followed, now ALOAD
            super.visitInsn(opcode);
            super.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, lastAStoreIndex);
            super.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, Type.getInternalName(Interceptor.class), "monitorEntered", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false);
        }
```

As a result the method seems not the be JIT compatible. `-XX:+PrintCompilation` shows:

```
  21938  619   !   3       com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)
  21938  619   !   3       com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   COMPILE SKIPPED: invalid parsing (retry at different tier)
               !m             @ 6   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
               !m             @ 13   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
  22105  716   !   4       com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)
  22105  716   !   4       com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   COMPILE SKIPPED: cannot parse method (not retryable)
               !m             @ 6   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
               !m             @ 13   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
               !m             @ 62   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
               !m             @ 13   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
               !m             @ 6   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
               !m                   @ 13   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
               !m                   @ 13   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
               !m             @ 6   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
               !m             @ 62   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl::checkColumnBounds (142 bytes)   not compilable (disabled)
```

I am aware that the instructions I am adding are nothing `javac` would generate but since it is valid bytecode (at least I thought so and the sample works) I was assuming that JIT can deal with it. It seems, however, that JIT is looking for some well-known patterns. I wonder how other JVM based languages deal with that. Do they always need to produce same / similar bytecode to what `javac` would generate?

The only theoretical solution I have in mind right now is to try to come up with `javac` like bytecode, which is of course more tricky than what I was trying to do here as I would need to store the monitor object in a new local variable and then load it from there before `monitorEnter` and do the same thing again before calling my interceptor. So I will either need to change to asm tree API (in order to go back again) or see if I can buffer the instructions to still be able to react accordingly in case I reach run into a `monitorEnter`. Any other suggestions that might be a little easier to implement?

Comment: It looks like indeed a problem in the way how the code is instrumented, but it's hard to say without seeing the actual bytecode. The symptoms suggest there might be an issue with JIT compilation. Try `-XX:+PrintCompilation`, `-XX:+PrintInlining` or heavier `-XX:LogCompilation` and `-XX:+PrintAssembly`. [JITWatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch) is a great tool for analyzing HotSpot compiler outcome.

Comment: `-XX:+PrintCompilation` shows some problems indeed. I updated the question with some more details.

Comment: Some methods that get not compiled get "not compilable (unbalanced monitors)".I found this statement "..methods with unstructured locking aren't compiled and fall back to the interpreter" [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/6c4bdbf90897/src/jdk.internal.vm.compiler/share/classes/org.graalvm.compiler.core.test/src/org/graalvm/compiler/core/test/UnbalancedMonitorsTest.java#l42). Am not sure yet why my changes might lead to that though.

Comment: “Unstructured locking” means that the code does not guaranty that `monitorenter` and `monitorexit` are always paired. There is an exception handler calling `monitorexit` if an exception occurred while holding the lock. Your injected code (the call to `Interceptor.monitorEntered(…)`) is called while holding the lock, but not covered by the exception handler, so if that method throws an exception, `monitorexit` is not called.

Comment: @Holger I have only concentrated on the issue with the method above so far and implemented the local variable approach. So now the instrumented byte code looks like it could have been created by `javac` (I compared both versions - a manual written one and an instrumented one - with `javap` and all byte codes are the same for the method above). Nevertheless I still get the same error. The hand written one gets compiled though. What else could lead to JIT having problems with parsing the method if not the byte code of the method itself?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you got me right. I *am* referring to the bytecode you have posted. The sequence of instructions may look identical to `javac` generated code, but the exception handler's protected range is from 16 to 133 whereas it should be 12 to 133, to cover your injected code as well, or, as the JVM would see it, it should cover everything after `monitorenter` up to `monitorexit`.

Comment: Didn't get you right indeed, sorry. I ignored the range for the exception handler completely :-/ That was it, fixed already. This way it even works without having `javac`like byte code, but with the simpler transformation I had earlier. Thanks a lot! Do you want to put it as official answer so I can accept it? Otherwise I'd just summarize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor lock contention, you can use Flight Recorder, which has practically no overhead when it comes to contention that takes more than 10-20 ms.

JDK 11:

```
java -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=recording.jfr ...
```

Earlier releases also requires -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures flag and can only be used for free for development.

If you want to profile shorter latencies, you can create a custom configuration file, i.e locks.jfc, using Java Mission Control (Window -> Template Manager), or use the configuration below. The default threshold is 20 ms, if not using a custom confirguration.

The name of the event (jdk.JavaMonitorEnter) has changed between releases, but this is fpr JDK 11, or later.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration version="2.0">
  <event name="jdk.JavaMonitorEnter">
    <setting name="enabled">true</setting>
    <setting name="stackTrace">true</setting>
    <setting name="threshold">20 ms</setting>
  </event>
</configuration>
```

The threshold can be lowered, but the overhead will increase dramatically if going below 1 ms. Most overhead is due to taking the stack traces, which only happens if the latency is longer than the threshold.

```
java -XX:StartFlightRecording:filename=recording.jfr,settings=locks.jfc
```

The lock instrumentation happens inside the JVM and the duration  of the latencies is measured using invariant TSC which only cost  about 10-15 ns.

The recording can be opened in JMC
https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jmc/7/

or the results can be accessed programatically:

```
try(Recording file : new RecordingFile(Path.of("recording.jfr")) {
  while (file.hasMoreEvents()) {
    System.out.println(file.readEvent());
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer the original question at all and looks more like JFR ads. Please note, that the question is *not* about contended lock profiling, but rather about instrumenting *all* `monitorenter` instructions (including uncontended). The purpose is *not* to find the lock contention issues, but to investigate why the instrumented code runs slower than non-instrumented.